# How to do a category level fuzzy match in opensearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, opensearch

I have a index(table) in opnesearch with name cat_master_list. Sharing the sample below

| code | category | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Specialty | Accu |
| 2 | Specialty | Punture |
| 3 | Specialty | Allergy |
| 4 | Specialty | Allergist |
| 5 | Procedure | Pediatric |
| 6 | Procedure | Surgery |
| 7 | Procedure | Immunology |
| 8 | Procedure | Specialist |

Now i know on how to do a fuzzy match search on specific columns
Sharing the sample query for that

```
    query = {
      'size': 3,
      'query': {
        'multi_match': {
          'query': 'Accu',
          'fields': ['name' ,'category'],
           "fuzziness":"AUTO"
        }
      }
    }
```

This above query will do the fuzzy match on all the rows for two columns.
Now I want to write a query where I can do a fuzzy match on specific rows.
Basically I want to run the above query where **category='Specialty'**.
I know that I can create a separate index but I want to do a category level search on same table.
Is that possible in opensearch?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for correctly, try using a [Boolean query](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/query-dsl/bool/).

For example:

```
{
  "size": 3,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Accu",
          "fields": [
            "name",
            "category"
          ],
          "fuzziness": "AUTO"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "category": "Specialty"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the difference between `filter` and `must` consult the documentation and adapt the query according to your case.

Comment: I understood the query but this query is giving me a empty set whereas when i run my query I get some output on the same index.

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how documents and their fields are defined in the mapping?

Comment: Every field is of type text.